# Flask SQL - Is it possible to dynamically set the column when inserting records

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

My problem: I am iterating through raw data to update a DB Table. Each item in the raw data is linked to one column (out of 19 different visa categories) in the DB Table. Is it possible to dynamically set which column I want to insert into the DB?

Example raw data:

```
{"continent": "Western Europe", "country": "austria", "visa_category": "Entry under European treaties", "traveller_passport": "Latvia"}
```

DB Model (not including it all as there are getters and setters for each one):

```
class PassportModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "passports"

    # Country ID specifies which country the passport holder is from.
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    country_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("country.id"))
    _european_treaty = db.Column(db.String)
    _remain_indefinitely = db.Column(db.String)
    _days_col_one    = db.Column('7_days', db.String)
    ...
```

The DB insert query I have attempted:

```
insert_to_db = PassportModel(country_id=db_country_id, getattr(PassportModel, 'european_treaty')='Value to insert')
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that by unpacking a [`kwargs`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769403/what-is-the-purpose-and-use-of-kwargs) dict.

```
kwargs = {'european_treaty': 'Value to insert')}

insert_to_db = PassportModel(country_id=db_country_id, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried this but I was getting the following error: 
`TypeError: __init__() keywords must be strings}`

Turns out I didn't need to include the getattr function when setting the kwargs so I adjusted your suggestion slightly and it worked:
`kwargs = {'european_treaty' : 'Value to insert'}`